# useEffect does not get correct value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am implementing a feature where the dropdown menu closes on tab/blur and automatically selects the highlighted item.

The component is structured in a way where the parent component renders it. When the dropdown component closes, it passes a callback to the parent which unmounts the dropdown component.

The issue is that the dropdown component itself does not know when the user closes it. The parent controls that state.

I would like to find a way to tell the parent component which item is currently highlighted so the parent can set that value. Only the dropdown component knows which item is currently highlighted.

I tried to add a callback to `useEffect`:

```
const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    props.onSelect(items[index])
  }
}, [])
```

This doesn't seem to work. It looks like `useEffect` is created on mount and does not hold the current state of the index. It seems that the index is always `0`.

I would like a way to fire this `onSelect` function on unmount while saving the index state. Maybe something like this:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  () => {
    props.onSelect(items[index]);
  }
}, [index]
```

The issue here is that whenever `index` changes, it calls `onSelect`, which closes the dropdown menu.

I would like the first `useEffect` to work while saving the index. Or somehow have the second `useEffect` to run only when the component unmounts.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please include a more [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example? Could we see the parent and child components?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code isn't sharable, remaking it from scratch will probably take some time for me since I'd have to create two components and hover states and whatnot.

Comment: That's ok, it need only be *an* example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The effect captured a stale value.

This is documented in the [React Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function) and there's a [handy hook called `useLatest`](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useLatest.md) in the `react-use` library that'll help with this.